# How to specify generic types at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, polymorphism

I have a piece of code like this:

```
  var senders = new List<MessageSenderBase<object>>();
  senders.Add(new MessageSender1<MessageType1>());
```

where `MessageSender1<MessageType1>` is derived from `MessageSenderBase<T>` and `MessageType1` is another class I defined.

Now the 2nd line has error which says `CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Demo.MessageSender.MessageSender1<Demo.MessageSender.MessageType1>' to 'Demo.MessageSender.MessageSenderBase<object>'`

How can I solve this issue?

My design is that `MessageSenderBase<T>` will sit in my library, and at the API level the user can derive their own sender class and specify their own type of message they want to send. I thought this would work since `object` is the base class of `MessageType1` and `MessageSenderBase<>` is the base class of `MessageSender1<>`.

Please help, thanks!

Edit - adding MessageSenderBase

```
    public class MessageSender1<MessageType1> : MessageSenderBase<MessageType1>
    {
        public override string Topic => "topic1";

        public async override Task SendAsync()
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    public abstract class MessageSenderBase<T>
    {
        public abstract string Topic { get;}
        public T Deserialize(string json)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
        public abstract Task SendAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what your `MessageSenderBase` class look like? Depending on what it look like this conversion from `MessageSender1<MessageType1>` to `MessageSender1<object>` may or may not make sense.

Comment: @Sweeper Please see my recent edit, thanks!

Comment: That is a compile-time static typing error. The runtime is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: If `MessageSenderBase<T>` just have that one method you showed, you can make it a [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) interface, then the conversion would work.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you, would it work if I have some implementation in my class? Please see my recent edit. I wouldn't be able to mark it as an interface.

Comment: To borrow someone else's quote "A bunch of bananas is not a fruit bowl". Your list elements must have a type that *all* elements implement. Perhaps introduce an interface to `MessageSenderBase<T>`, or `MessageSenderBase<T> : MessageSenderBase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to work around this is to add a new [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) interface that has the "shape" of `MessageSenderBase<T>`:

```
public interface IMessageSender<out T> {
    string Topic { get; }
    T Deserialize(string json);
    Task SendAsync();
}
public abstract class MessageSenderBase<T>: IMessageSender<T>
{
    public abstract string Topic { get;}
    public T Deserialize(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
    public abstract Task SendAsync();
}
```

If you now make your list to be of type `List<IMessageSender<object>>`, you can put `AnyMessageSender<AnythingReferenceType>` in it.

```
var senders = new List<IMessageSender<object>>();
senders.Add(new MessageSender1<MessageType1>());
```

Note that if `MessageSenderBase` has a method that takes a `T` as parameter (or more generally, has a `T` in an "input position"), you should not include that in `IMessageSender`, because if you did, it is not safe to convert from `MessageSender1<MessageType1>` to `IMessageSender<object>` anymore. Imagine if you had:

```
public interface IMessageSender<out T> {
    ...
    void Foo(T someT); // suppose this is implemented in MessageSender1
}
```

And you would be able to do:

```
var senders = new List<IMessageSender<object>>();
senders.Add(new MessageSender1<MessageType1>());
senders[0].Foo("abc"); // let's try giving a string to Foo
```

But `senders[0]` is a `MessageSender1<MessageType1>` object. `MessageSender1<MessageType1>.Foo` only accepts `MessageType1` objects, not string!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll need to further learn about covariance. I almost had the exact same thing but just missing the ''out'' keyword for my interface.

Comment: While you are figuring out _covariance_, go all the way any read up on _contravariance_ (using `in` instead of `out`)